# How to convert string representing a decimal using parseInt instead of parseFloat?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, parseint

Given a string that represents a number use parseInt to convert string to number. I wrote a working function, but did not account for decimal numbers. Is there a way to convert decimals using parseInt? This is as far as I've gotten trying to account for decimals. The problem with this is NaN being returned. I can't think of a solution to implement that filters NaN from the results. The ultimate goal is to compare the two strings. My solution must use parseInt.

```
function convertStr(str1, str2) {
let num1 = str1.split('')
let num2 = str2.split('');
num1 = num1.map(str => parseInt(str));
num2 = num2.map(str => parseInt(str));
console.log(num1);
console.log(num2);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I need to .split('.') on the decimal point. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Do you want the `num`s to be an array of numbers, representing each digit (without decimals)?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good step to what you are seeking for :

**The question is** : What do you want as output when encountering decimal value?

```js
// Soluce to replace NaN by '.'
function convertStrReplace(str1) {
  let num1 = str1.split('')
  
  num1 = num1.map(str => parseInt(str)).map(x => isNaN(x) ? '.' : x);
  
  console.log(num1);
}

// Soluce to ignore NaN
function convertStrIgnore(str1) {
  let num1 = str1.split('')
  
  num1 = num1.map(str => parseInt(str)).filter(x => !isNaN(x));
  
  console.log(num1);
}


convertStrReplace('17,52');
convertStrIgnore('17,52');
```

---

**Syntax alternative**

```js
function convertStrFilter(str1) {
  const num1 = [
    ...str1,
  ].map(str => parseInt(str)).filter(x => !isNaN(x));

  console.log(num1);
}

convertStrFilter('17,52');
```

---

**Explaination about integer and string differences**

```js
// String and integer differences

// Put a number into a string
const str = '9000';

console.log(typeof str, str);

// Put a number into a number
const number = 9000;

console.log(typeof number, number);

// Compare both (compare value and type)
console.log('equality ===', str === number);

// Compare both (compare value)
console.log('equality ==', str == number);

const numberFromString = parseInt(str);

console.log(typeof numberFromString, numberFromString);

// Compare both (compare value and type)
console.log('equality ===', number === numberFromString);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think that these answers will put me in the right direction and help me solve the problem. It was part of a practice problem, and my biggest take away is to ask more questions. Will the string represent an integer, etc... Had I thought of this in my original solution I wouldn't be figuring this out now.

Comment: @J.Sutliff I've added a snippet explaining the difference between integer and strings